# Equivalent Proverb in English

Tags: nouns, proverb-requests

There is a proverb in Urdu, "Bacha bola nahi bola nahi muh khola to Amma maro Bawa maro bola".

This could be translated as, *the kid never spoke, but when he did*, (to his concerned parents shock) he said, *may my father die, may my mother die.*

Is there any similar proverb in English?

Comment: What does is mean? What is it trying to say? Is it talking about when you try to help someone, and they turn against you?

Comment: Look at "calm before the storm" and tell us whether it is close to what you want.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Yes, this is what it means.

Comment: There's 'don't bite the hand that feeds you', but I'm not sure it's exactly the same meaning.

Comment: In my opinion, the proverb should be the combination of 'calm before the strom' and 'don't bite the hand that feeds you'

Comment: It means the most eagerly awaited thing eventually turns out to be set against you. Now can someone pitch in with a pithy saying?

Comment: "In my opinion, the proverb should be the combination of ... and 'don't bite the hand that feeds you' ". But there's no directive/proscription // rebuke implicit in the original. @Kris's interpretation seems most felicitous.

Answer (score 2):

I think the sentiment is simply

> **Be careful what you wish for.**

(David M changed his mind about this.)

From [UsingEnglish.com](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/be+careful+what+you+wish+for.html):

> *What does 'Be careful what you wish for' mean?*
>
> If you get things that you desire, there may be unforeseen and
>   unpleasant consequences.
>
> ('Be careful what you wish for, lest it come true.' and 'Be careful
>   what you wish for; you may receive it.' are also used.)

Comment: Yeah. I had that at first. But in reading the comments, it didn't convey the sense of calm before the storm.

Comment: ...'Cause you just might get it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the meaning correctly, I think the closest I can think of is:

> For there to have been betrayal, there must have been trust first.

It's less of a proverb than a quote by [Suzanne Collins](http://www.wiseoldsayings.com/betrayal-quotes/)